# Phaser 3 : Distort shape of grid

Tags: game-engine, phaser-framework, phaserjs

If there is grid with 5x5, how to make the grid distort like the image below ? The reason is to make a walk way, the nearest is bigger tiles, furthest is smaller tiles, and able to dynamic prepend 5x1 on top

[image]

[image]

Comment: So far I know this is no possible out-of-the-box, but with some Math and the graphics object you culd build this yourself.

Comment: What exactly is your usecase? should it be a racing game like grid, that should move, or just simulate movement, or is it fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to draw it yourself, you can use builtin functions to help with that. I created a short demo showing, how I would approach this problem, using Phaser's `graphics`, 'line' - gameobject, `intersects` and some other stuff. *(it might help)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: { create }
}; 

function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'Draw Grid 5 x 5')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    let graphics = this.add.graphics({ lineStyle: { width: 1, color: 0xaa00aa } });

    let leftX = config.width/2 - ( 50 * 5);
    let vertricalLines = [];

    // create vertical helper lines 
    for(let lineIdx = 0; lineIdx < 6; lineIdx++){
        let line = new Phaser.Geom.Line(config.width/2, 10, leftX, config.height -15);
        vertricalLines.push(line)
        leftX += 100;
    }

    // draw horziontal and vertical lines
    let bottomY = config.height - 15;
    let height = 40;
    for(let lineIdx = 0; lineIdx < 7; lineIdx++){
        let horizontalLine = new Phaser.Geom.Line(config.width/2 - ( 50 * 5), bottomY, leftX, bottomY);
        let startPoint = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        let endPoint = { x: 0, y: 0 };

        Phaser.Geom.Intersects.LineToLine(vertricalLines[0], horizontalLine, startPoint);
        Phaser.Geom.Intersects.LineToLine(vertricalLines[vertricalLines.length - 1], horizontalLine, endPoint);
        let drawLine = new Phaser.Geom.Line(startPoint.x, bottomY, endPoint.x, bottomY);
        graphics.strokeLineShape(drawLine);
        bottomY -= height;
        height *= .75
        
        if(lineIdx == 6){
            vertricalLines.forEach(line =>{
                let point = { x: 0, y: 0 };
                Phaser.Geom.Intersects.LineToLine(line, horizontalLine, point);
                line.x1 = point.x;
                line.y1 = point.y;
                graphics.strokeLineShape(line);
            });
        }
    }
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

> **Disclaimer:**
> I usually don't code the whole solution, just help find a solution *(but I wanted to try it out myself)*. And the following code is a crude/fast solution, it might not be the best way to solve this, and/or could need some improvement.

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: { create }
}; 

function create () {
    let infoLabel = this.add.text(10,10, 'Draw Grid 5 x 5')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    let button = this.add.rectangle(10, 45, 120, 30, 0x00ff00 )
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setDepth(100)
        .setInteractive();

    let buttonLabel = this.add.text(10,10, 'Add row')
        .setScale(1)
        .setDepth(101)
        .setColor('#000000')
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial', aligin: 'Center'});

    Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(buttonLabel, button);

    this.grid = this.add.graphics({ lineStyle: { width: 1, color: 0xaa00aa } })
        .setInteractive(new Phaser.Geom.Rectangle(0, 0, config.width, config.height), Phaser.Geom.Rectangle.Contains);

    button.on('pointerdown', () => {
        this.maxRows++;
        drawGrid( this );
    });

    this.grid.on('pointerdown', p => {
        infoLabel.setText('');
        let selectedCols = this.cols.map( ( col, idx ) => {
            return { idx, wasClicked:Phaser.Geom.Triangle.Contains(col, p.x, p.y)}
        }).filter( i => i.wasClicked);

        if(selectedCols[0]){
            let selectedRows = this.rows.map( ( row, idx ) => ({ idx, wasClicked: Phaser.Geom.Polygon.Contains(row, p.x, p.y)}))
                .filter( i => i.wasClicked);
            if(selectedRows[0]){
                infoLabel.setText(`Cell ( ${ selectedCols[0].idx }, ${ selectedRows[0].idx } )`);
            }
        }
    });

    this.maxRows = 5;
    drawGrid( this );
}

function drawGrid(scene){   
    scene.grid.clear();

    let leftX = config.width/2 - ( 50 * 5);
    let vertricalLines = [];
    let horizontaLines = [];

    scene.cols = [];
    scene.rows = [];

    // create vertical helper lines 
    for(let lineIdx = 0; lineIdx < 6; lineIdx++){
        let line = new Phaser.Geom.Line(config.width/2, 10, leftX, config.height -15);
        vertricalLines.push(line)
        leftX += 100;

        // just for interactivity
        if(lineIdx > 0 ){
            let lastLine = vertricalLines[lineIdx -1];
            scene.cols.push(
                new Phaser.Geom.Triangle ( line.x1, line.y1, line.x2 , line.y2, lastLine.x2, lastLine.y2)
            );
        }
    }

    // draw horziontal and vertical lines
    let bottomY = config.height - 15;
    let height = 40;
    for(let lineIdx = 0; lineIdx < scene.maxRows ; lineIdx++){
        let horizontalLine = new Phaser.Geom.Line(config.width/2 - ( 50 * 5), bottomY, leftX, bottomY);
        let startPoint = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        let endPoint = { x: 0, y: 0 };

        horizontaLines.push(horizontalLine);

        Phaser.Geom.Intersects.LineToLine(vertricalLines[0], horizontalLine, startPoint);
        Phaser.Geom.Intersects.LineToLine(vertricalLines[vertricalLines.length - 1], horizontalLine, endPoint);

        scene.grid.strokeLineShape(new Phaser.Geom.Line(startPoint.x, bottomY, endPoint.x, bottomY));

        bottomY -= height;
        height *= .75
        
        if(lineIdx == scene.maxRows - 1){
            vertricalLines.forEach(line =>{
                let point = { x: 0, y: 0 };
                Phaser.Geom.Intersects.LineToLine(line, horizontalLine, point);
                line.x1 = point.x;
                line.y1 = point.y;
                scene.grid.strokeLineShape(line);
            });
        }
   
        // just for interactivity
        if(lineIdx > 0 ){
            let lastLine = horizontaLines[lineIdx -1];
            scene.rows.push(
                new Phaser.Geom.Polygon ( [horizontalLine.x1, horizontalLine.y1, horizontalLine.x2 , horizontalLine.y2, lastLine.x2, lastLine.y2, lastLine.x1, lastLine.y1 ])
            );
        }
    }
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thank for the reply ! Is this possible to make each of the box clickable and able to prepend 5x1

Comment: @FeelRightz I updated my answer with a small demo covering the to points asked. So the answer is yes it is possible, but everything has to be coded by hand.